# How to get a popup box after submitting a form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

**[SOLVED]** Thanks everyone that replied.

I've got a PHP script that is run after a user submited a contact form.
This script shows a message in the top left corner saying if it worked properly or if it encountered a problem.

Now my question is, how can I put those messages into a popup box?
I know there is JS involved, but I barely have knowledge of that.

( Example: http://www.dylanvanheugten.nl/contact.php)

---

#### PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Site Contact';
$to = 'info@dylanvanheugten.nl';
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != '') {
        if ($human == '12') {                
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                echo '<p>Uw bericht is verzonden.<br/> U krijgt binnen 3 werkdagen een bericht terug.</p>';
            } else { 
                echo '<p>Er is iets mis gegaan tijdens het versturen van uw bericht.<br/> Probeert u alstublieft nogmaals.</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '12') {
            echo '<p>U heeft de spam preventie som foutief beantwoord.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Alstublieft alle velden invullen.</p>';
    }
}
```

---

#### HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <label>Naam</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Naam">

    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">

    <label>Onderwerp</label>
    <input name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp">

    <label>Bericht</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Laat hier ook uw telefoonnummer achter als u telefonisch contact wilt."></textarea>

    <label><strong>*Spam preventie*</strong><br/>Wat is 11+1?</label>
    <input name="human" placeholder="11 + 1 =">

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzend">
    <label><u>Alle velden zijn verplicht.</u></label>
</form>
```

Comment: submit your form using ajax then on complete callback call some jquery plugin i.e. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and pass data. Also your php code that handles submit needs to return data you will pass to colorbox.

Comment: please do avoid using alert, it is not user friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose your `echo` with `<script>` tags like this.

```
echo '<script>alert("Alstublieft alle velden invullen");<script>';
```

Comment: I've used this solution, for now atleast. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the same way that you can print HTML from PHP, you can 'print' javascript. Here's an example with an alert box:

```
print("<script>window.alert('This is a javascript alert from PHP');</script>");
```

You are able to put your PHP variables inside of the statement, as well, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `alert msg` like,

```
$msg='';
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != '') {
        if ($human == '12') {                
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                $msg='Uw bericht is verzonden.<br/> U krijgt binnen 3 werkdagen een bericht terug';
            } else { 
                $msg='Er is iets mis gegaan tijdens het versturen van uw bericht.<br/> Probeert u alstublieft nogmaals.'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '12') {
            $msg='U heeft de spam preventie som foutief beantwoord.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg='Alstublieft alle velden invullen.';
    }
    echo '<script>
             alert("'.$msg.'");
          </script>';
    // you can replace the above javscript code to any plugin like jquery ui modal box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some javascript to the top of your html markup where you define a method to display a popup. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayPopup()
{
 alert("Form submitted!");
}
</script>
```

Then within your PHP when the form has been submitted, just call the method *displayPopup()* method within a script tag.

You can certainly optimise the approach above, but it should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: The benefit of defining your popup method rather than doing it all inline is that you can further customise what you want to happen on submission of the form e.g. change the CSS of something on the form, or pass in a parameter to customise the message, etc. The inline alert is just as valid, but having a defined method gives more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Store the error message in a variable and simply echo them in the required div.

```
if ($_POST['submit']) 
{
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $subject != '' && $message != '') 
    {
        if ($human == '12') 
        {                
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
            { 
                $message = '<p>Uw bericht is verzonden.<br/> U krijgt binnen 3 werkdagen een bericht terug.</p>';
            } else 
            { 
                $message = '<p>Er is iets mis gegaan tijdens het versturen van uw bericht.<br/> Probeert u alstublieft nogmaals.</p>'; 
            } 
        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '12') 
        {
            $message =  '<p>U heeft de spam preventie som foutief beantwoord.</p>';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        $message = '<p>Alstublieft alle velden invullen.</p>';
    }
}
```

And in your HTML, you can create a  and display the error inside it:

```
<div id="errorMessage"> <?php echo $message; ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
if ($query) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('data Updated successfully!'); window.location.href = 'home.php';</script>";              
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('ERROR! Something Went wrong. Try Again')</script>";
}
```